# Editing MySQL entries with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have searched and searched for answer to this question and similar questions, but I have been unsuccessful.
I have a database, and an option that allows me to EDIT and DELETE entries in the database, I can DELETE entries perfectly fine, but I cant seem to EDIT them, I have attached the code, if any one has any idea at all, it would be amazing, thanks so much in advance.

```
<?php
require_once('includes/connection.php');
// initialize flags
$OK = false;
$done = false;
// get details of selected record
//if (isset($_GET['band_id']) && !$_POST) {
  if (isset($_GET['band_id'])) {
  // prepare SQL query
  $sql = 'SELECT band_id, email, bandname, bio, state, genre, link, sound FROM submit
          WHERE band_id = ?';
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  // bind the results using numbers to reference the columns used in the select statement
  $stmt->bindColumn(1, $band_id);
  $stmt->bindColumn(2, $email);
  $stmt->bindColumn(3, $bandname);
  $stmt->bindColumn(4, $bio);
  $stmt->bindColumn(5, $state);
  $stmt->bindColumn(6, $genre);
  $stmt->bindColumn(7, $link);
  $stmt->bindColumn(8, $sound);
  // execute query by passing array of variables
  $OK = $stmt->execute(array($_GET['band_id']));
  $stmt->fetch();
}
// if form has been submitted, update record
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
  // prepare update query
  $sql = 'UPDATE submit SET email = ?, bandname = ?, bio = ?, state = ?, genre = ?, link = ?, sound = ?
          WHERE band_id = ?';
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  // execute query by passing array of variables
  $stmt->execute(array($_POST['band_id'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['bandname'], $_POST['bio'], $_POST['state'], $_POST['genre'], $_POST['link'], $_POST['sound']));
  $done = $stmt->rowCount();
}
// redirect if $_GET['band_id'] not defined
if ($done || !isset($_GET['band_id'])) {
  header('Location: http://localhost/giggedin/submit.php');
  exit;
}
// display error message if query fails
if (isset($stmt) && !$OK && !$done) {
  $error = $stmt->errorInfo();
  if (isset($error[2])) {
    $error = $error[2];
  }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="Find a support band for you band with us">
    <meta name="author" content="Chris Beechey, Copyright 2016">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Music, Australia, Band, Show, Gig">
    <link rel="icon" href="">
        <title>GIGGEDIN - FIND A BAND</title>

    <!--- BOOTSTRAP ------->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" >
    <!--- CSS FOR WHOLE PAGE STYLE -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <!--- CSS FOR NAV BAR -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nav.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/form.css">
    <!--- FONTS ------------->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Oswald|Architects+Daughter' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ionicons.min.css">  

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
  <header>
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        <a href="submit.php">Submit Band</a>
        <a href="search.php">Search Bands</a>


      <div class="social">
        <h4>Follow us</h4>
          <i class="ion-social-facebook"></i>
          <i class="ion-social-twitter"></i>
          <i class="ion-social-instagram"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;color:antiquewhite;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; MENU</span>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="container">
            <h3>admin only - Edit</h3>

            <?php 
if (isset($error)) {
  echo "<p class='warning'>Error: $error</p>";
}
if($band_id == 0) { ?>
  <p class="warning">Invalid request: record does not exist.</p>
<?php } else { ?>

    <form role="form" method="post" action="search.php">
        <fieldset>
              <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Band ID</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="band_id" name="band_id" value="<?php echo htmlentities($band_id); ?>" />
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlentities($email); ?>" />
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="bandname" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Band Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bandname" name="bandname" value="<?php echo htmlentities($bandname); ?>" />
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="bio" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Brief Bio</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">   
                <textarea name="bio" class="form-control" id="bio" rows="5" value="<?php echo htmlentities($bio); ?>" /></textarea>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="state" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">State</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="state" class="form-control" id="state" value="<?php echo htmlentities($state); ?>" />
                    <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
                    <option value="SA">SA</option>
                    <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
                    <option value="WA">WA</option>
                    <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
                    <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
                    <option value="NT">NT</option>
                    <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
                </select>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="genre" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Genre</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="genre" class="form-control" id="genre" value="<?php echo htmlentities($genre); ?>" />
                    <option value="rock">ROCK</option>
                    <option value="punk">PUNK</option>
                    <option value="blues">BLUES</option>
                    <option value="bluesrock">BLUES/ROCK</option>
                    <option value="metal">METAL</option>
                    <option value="jazz">JAZZ</option>
                    <option value="acoustic">ACOUSTIC</option>
                    <option value="solo">SOLO</option>
                </select>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="link" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">FB/Website Link:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="url" class="form-control" id="link" name="link" size="30" value="<?php echo htmlentities($link); ?>" />
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="sound"class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Sound/Video Link:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="url" class="form-control" id="sound" name="sound" size="30" value="<?php echo htmlentities($sound); ?>" />
            </div>
    </div>
            <input type="submit" name="update" value="update" class="submit" id="update" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
  <?php } ?>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: error messages?  is `$_POST['update']` set, what does `but I have been unsuccessful` mean

Comment: Just from reading it this one `$_POST['band_id']` should be last in your execute array, in order for the `?` marks.

Comment: I would also try to make the code example more minimal. A lof ot irrelevant code here.

Comment: Also, in general, I can recommend displaying/logging the generated query for problems like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your gonna want the order of these to match

```
 $sql = 'UPDATE submit SET email = ?, bandname = ?, bio = ?, state = ?, genre = ?, link = ?, sound = ?
      WHERE band_id = ?';
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
 // execute query by passing array of variables
 $stmt->execute(array($_POST['band_id'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['bandname'], $_POST['bio'], $_POST['state'], $_POST['genre'], $_POST['link'], $_POST['sound']));
```

Specifically

```
 $_POST['band_id']
```

Should be last in the list not first.  So just change it to this:

```
 $stmt->execute(array($_POST['email'], $_POST['bandname'], $_POST['bio'], $_POST['state'], $_POST['genre'], $_POST['link'], $_POST['sound'], $_POST['band_id']));
```

Is this PDO? or mysqli.  If its pdo ( looks like pdo, I haven't used mysqli in about 3 years ) you can do named parameters and avoid that issue.

```
  $sql = 'UPDATE submit SET email = :email, bandname = :bandname , bio = :bio, state = :state, genre = :genre, link = :link, sound = :sound
      WHERE band_id = :band_id';
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
 // execute query by passing array of variables
 $stmt->execute(array($_POST[':band_id'], $_POST[':email'], $_POST[':bandname'], $_POST[':bio'], $_POST[':state'], $_POST[':genre'], $_POST[':link'], $_POST[':sound']));
```

You just have to add the `:` if it's PDO

Comment: Do `var_export(  $_POST )` or `print_r( $_POST )` or `var_dump( $_POST )` and make sure the post values are what they should be.

Comment: Its working now, not too sure what happened, I think I had too many commons or something tiny, but its working now!